# Git binary patch as text applying has many whitespace errors

Tags: git, warnings, whitespace, binaryfiles, git-diff

When using `git diff -a` for text, for example `git diff --no-index -a dir1 dir2 > dir.patch`, when I apply the patch with `git apply` I get many whitespace warnings about trailing whitespace and squelching thousands of whitespace errors. Should I be worried about these? `diff` shows the patched directory is byte identical to its expected patched state, so nothing got corrupted. (I am aware `--binary` takes care of these errors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be worried about [Git's whitespace-error warnings]?

Only if you agree with Git's rather opinionated stance on whitespace.  That is, by default, Git thinks that it is bad to have a line in a file end with whitespace.  If we let the symbol `$` represent the end of a line, then:

```
hello world$
```

is OK, but:

```
hello world $
```

is not.  While most Git commands say nothing about this, `git diff` *highlights* the "bad" whitespace, and `git apply` *complains about* the "bad" whitespace.

If you *don't* agree with Git (and/or if such whitespace is important), you can configure Git, or use command line arguments to `git apply`, to change what it complains about or to disable complaints.  If you think Git is right on, you can turn `git apply`'s complaints into outright errors, rather than warnings, or tell Git to fix such errors (e.g., to strip the trailing blank from the above line).

For a complete list of whitespace options, see the `core.whitespace` settings described in [the git-config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Those rules make some sense for source code. I am asking if they are justified at all for git diffs with binary data from `-a`.

Comment: Probably not—but Git warns anyway, unless you tell it not to (`git apply --whitespace=nowarn`); it's just treating them as text, like you asked it to :-)